# Using the YouTube v3 Api in Windows Phone 8 Development

Tags: windows, api, windows-phone-8, youtube

I've spent hours trying to find some info on how to use the YouTube V3 Api .NET library in Windows Phone 8 development. Even Nokia themselves are no help at all, because their Wiki page just shows how to do things using WebClient (and even there it isn't that clear).

I already have a lot of trouble finding any guides or anything related to the .NET library for the YouTube v3 Api, and I've been following off sample code which doesn't seem to work (this one in particular - https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/dotnet/Search.cs)

So could someone write up or link me to some Windows Phone 8 sample code that uses the .NET library, for example, to search something on YouTube?

Comment: Have you been able to use Youtube v3 API?? I also need some help. Please reply..

Answer (score 1):

The framework "[MyToolkit](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube)" does not contain any search youtube api methods, but it is very easy to search for youtube videos see below (sample code)

```
    private void doYouTubeSearch()
    {
        if (YouTubeSearchText.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            this.LoadingProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += DownloadStringCompleted;
            var searchUri = string.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={0}&format=6", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(YouTubeSearchText.Text));
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(searchUri));
        }
    }

    void DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var atomns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
        var medians = XNamespace.Get("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
        var xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
        var videos = (
          from entry in xml.Descendants(atomns.GetName("entry"))
          select new YouTubeViewModel
          {
              VideoId = entry.Element(atomns.GetName("id")).Value,
              VideoImageUrl = (
                from thumbnail in entry.Descendants(medians.GetName("thumbnail"))
                where thumbnail.Attribute("height").Value == "360"
                select thumbnail.Attribute("url").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
              Title = entry.Element(atomns.GetName("title")).Value,
              Description = entry.Element(atomns.GetName("content")).Value
          }).ToArray();  .... more code here :-)
```

... and you can filter etc. in this...

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any Api access key related with windows phone 8 in developer console. Maybe that's why the sample doesn't work (?)